# Handling keystore file?

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

As for react native android app, in Visual Studio docs of signing, it says that if my keystore is not within my repo, then I need to upload my key store file `contractor-release-key.keystore` and set credentials in app center, and that's what I did, however, in the build, I got this error:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: ***.  *** must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain
```

Also, in build.gradle if I set:

```
releaseSigningConfig {
            storeFile rootProject.file("app/contractor-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword System.getenv("APPCENTER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("APPCENTER_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("APPCENTER_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
```

I get error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '/Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/android/app/contractor-release-key.keystore' not found for signing config 'releaseSigningConfig'.
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

When I add all signing into build.gradle and include keystore file into repository, but I got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-54:19 to override.
```

Comment: It seems like the alias name and password should be incorrect. Because obviously it wont try to distribute (or perform that process) if it didnt have a .keystore file. I usually don't place my keystore in the repo either, have you perhaps tried to use a .jks file instead for signing?

Answer (score 5):

**To fix the problem:**

1. You need to remove or comment out any release or debug config inside your `android/app/build.gradle` as we will let AppCenter figure it out in the dashboard.
2. Go to AppCenter dashboard and add your keystore credentials to AppCenter and make sure you upload the keystore file as well.
3. Commit the changes you made inside `android/app/build.gradle` to your repository.
4. Run the build again inside App Center branch.

This should fix your problem.

If you are wondering why we do this. This is because AppCenter is designed to handle the whole signing process step for you so you do not need to add any gradle config to the repository yourself inside `android/app/build.gradle` or anywhere else on the repository. The whole purpose of having the environment config outside of the repository is because it's a good security practice. I know the documentation for AppCenter does not make this very clear.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem too. That is about keystore not for release signing.

As one of solution try to open your project in android studio, because of sync and refactor. Try to build there and check for recomendations

Can you tell me your gradle version? There could be some syntaxis error with libraries in gradle version higher than 3.

p.s. Do not judge strictly, but I really want to help solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it suddenly happened and I had to to re-upload the exact same keystore file as well as key password and alias in order to fix it.